# After rewriting wordpress website in laravel photos not displaying

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel

Moved website from wordpress to laravel . So now my images in /public/wp-content/uploads/filename.jpg.
But any image is not displayed in site .
[image: Here error not found]

But actually I have this image
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your directory name is (wp_content) but you used (wp-content) in url.You should replace (_) with (-) in your directory name.